# Rendering HighCharts to class instead of id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts

I have the following which works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    get_data_for_chart();

    function get_data_for_chart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_data.aspx?rand=' + Math.random(),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function(results) { 
                var chart1;

                chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart( {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'portlet_content_18',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Where the HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="portlet_content_18">
```

The user can dynamically select which `portlet` s/he wants on screen.  S/He can also select to have the same `portlet` on the screen more than once for comparison reasons.

So if the HTML ends up becoming:

```
<div id="portlet_content_18">
<div id="portlet_content_18">
```

Only the first `div` gets populated with the chart, and the second one remains blank.  How can I get around this issue?

Comment: You can't have multiple id's but you can try with 'class'. Change it to class="port-18" and make sure you update it on 'success'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can. See their example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/renderto-jquery/

basically you assign an jQuery element to a variable:

`renderTo: $('.myclass')[0]`

Comment: I have tried that, but I am not having much luck.  Here is a jsfiddle of what I have tried.: http://jsfiddle.net/Chmts/

Comment: Using just $container will not work. As the jsfiddle from highcharts demonstrates, you must specify $container[0].

Answer (score 15):

As Ido already [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996778/rendering-highcharts-to-class-instead-of-id#comment14367844_10996778), you can't have multiple ids, but you can have multiple classes.

I had to do the following:

```
var $containers = $('.container'),
    chartConfig = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: null,
            defaultSeriesType: 'column'
        }
    };

$containers.each(function(i, e){
    chartConfig.chart.renderTo = e;
    new Highcharts.Chart(chartConfig);
});
```

Also, you don't really have to assign the Chart object to a variable - at least I didn't want to.

Hope it helps somebody.