# Is it possible to have multiple highcharts with one id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, haml

I have the following scenario in `haml`:

```
#ownershipChart{"chart-data" => [["pie1", 100], ["pie2", 150], ["pie3", 200]]}
#ownershipChart{"chart-data" => [["pie4", 45], ["pie5", 50], ["pie6", 20]]}
```

and in javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('#ownershipChart').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title:{
      text: 'Ownership'
    },
    plotOptions:{
      pie:{
        allowPointSelect: true
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Ownership',
      data: $('#ownershipChart').attr('chart-data')
    }]
  });
});
```

As you can figure, I'm trying to create one highcharts function that applies across these two charts at the same time. First, I know this is incorrect because `$('#ownershipChart').attr('chart-data')` isn't returning anything. Second, is this the right way to think about it? I'm currently dynamically generating the `haml` `div id="ownershipChart"` so dynamically generating a highcharts js object every time also feels wrong.

What's the best way to generate multiple highcharts when the `div` `id`s they are attached to is unknown and varies user by user?

Comment: can't we use class here?

Comment: I tried @Rory solution below, but can't get `$(this).attr('chart-data')` to actually return data in set in the object.

Comment: @locoboy, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996778/rendering-highcharts-to-class-instead-of-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could instead use a class, and loop through each instance creating the chart as you go. Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ownershipChart').each(function()  {
        $(this).highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Ownership'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Ownership',
                data: $(this).attr('chart-data')
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Note that the `data` property is filled by a reference to `this`, which means the data will be read from the current element in the iteration.

Comment: I believe highcharts doesn't let you use a class.

Comment: It does when you use the jQuery connector, as you are. Using the native JS implementation then it only allows the use of `id` attributes as it uses `getElementById` internally.

Comment: When I tried this the data wasn't loading in the highcharts object. I did confirm through an alert that `$(this).attr('chart-data')` works though. Do you know what could be wrong that `data: $(this).attr('chart-data')` is not compiling?

Comment: I would start a new question for that, as this question is about attaching the chart to individual elements, whereas that is to do with the format of the provided object.

Comment: How can I confirm that this is right though and that it works with highcharts?

Comment: I figured out the problem - basically `$(this).attr('chart-data')` was returned as a string and highcharts only accepts it as an array.