# Highcharts.js not working inside slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, slick.js

[working at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7npqI.jpg)

[then it breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0klu.jpg)

Im using high charts.js inside slick carousal and it works only for the 1st instance and it hide the chat and then again it shows in the third instance.

```
            Highcharts.chart('pie7', {
                series: [{
                        data: [{
                                name: 'Chrome',
                                y: 61.41,
                                sliced: true,
                                selected: true
                            }, {
                                name: 'Internet Explorer',
                                y: 11.84
                            }, {
                                name: 'Other',
                                y: 7.05
                            }]
                    }]
            });


                           $('.chartslick').slick({
                   dots: false,
                   slidesToShow: 6,
                   slidesToScroll: 1,
                   autoplay: true,
                   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
               });
```

Example

https://jsfiddle.net/v6s0nbhu/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with `infinite:true`. change this to false and check.

```
          $('.chartslick').slick({
               dots: false,
               slidesToShow: 6,
               slidesToScroll: 1,
               autoplay: true,
               autoplaySpeed: 2000,
               infinite: false
           });
```

you have added id for charts. infinite is copy all the slider without id. so hightchart cannot initialize in 2nd step.

you need to use infinite false or change the pie chart `id` to `class`

[Rendering HighCharts to class instead of id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996778/rendering-highcharts-to-class-instead-of-id)